# sending ether via contract execution

Tags: solidity

how to write a contract that send ether from one account to another account based on some criteria. well, i have tried address.send(4 ether) method but that's not helping me , error comes low level code. And where this .send() method send ether when we apply it.

i think it is very clear because this question is viral in solidity developer as beginner and no one is giving more appropriate answer to this question. ok let me address this question again -

i want to send few ether to another account and for this i am using .send method

example  = address.send(3 ether)

but this code is giving me error as low level code so it cannot be executed.

as i want to send few ether to any account and don't any other way to send it...

please give me answer with example and i am trying this code to my ethereum wallet on window.. i think this is appropriate question to understand it.

thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you meant by **problem in code**

Comment: well , i have tried lots of  scenario but nothing helping me.. solidity language is i think easy to understand by tough to implement, anyone help me out of this.

Comment: well i also want to develop smart contract that send ether from one account to another based on some condition. here i have tried account.send(2 ether) but saying low level code.

Comment: Please, don't add comments but edit your question for clarifications.

Comment: hey, i have edited and narrowed my question and this time my question is very specific and easily understandable, so please give me answer and reopen my Question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found something...

```
function  Transfer(address _user2, uint _amount) {
    ...
    balances[user2] += _amount;
}
```

There is a variable mismatch: `_user2` and `user2`, right?